# Make average of values inside array to smooth graph line

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an `array` which represents the points of a graph with different values like the following one:

```
var array = [5, 3, 4, 1, 2];
```

I would like to loop through it and create a new array where the new values are:

- An average between the value preceding it and the one coming after it.
- Placed among the existing ones.

This means that `array[0]` will remain at the same position, while the other values will be pushed of one position. The new array should look like this:

```
var newArray = [5, 4, 3, 3.5, 4, 2.5, 1, 1.5, 2];
```

Do you have an idea on how to achieve this? Thanks in advance to your replies!

Comment: Please show what work you have already done. Code would be best.

Comment: If you find a solution in the answers, be sure to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var array = [5, 3, 4, 1, 2];
var newArr = [array[0]]; // start the array with the first from the original

array.reduce((a, b) => {
  newArr.push((a + b) / 2, b);
  return b;
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = [5, 3, 4, 1, 2];

var newArray = [];
newArray.push(array[0]);

for(var i=0; i < array.length-1; i++)
{
  var first = array[i];
  var second = array[i+1];
  var avg = (first+second)/2;
  newArray.push(avg);
  newArray.push(second);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5utkvge8/

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to loop through your original array, pushing each number to the new one, and if you are not on the final element, get the average of `array[i]` and `array[i+1]`

```
var array = [5, 3, 4, 1, 2];
var newArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
  newArray.push(array[i])
  if (!isNaN(array[i+1])) 
  {
    newArray.push((array[i] + array[i+1]) / 2)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

or in a functional, no-side effects, way:

```
var array = [5, 3, 4, 1, 2];
var newArray = array.reduce((result, value, index, array) => result.concat(index > 0 && index < array.length ? [(array[index-1] + value)/2, value] : value), [])
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you can modify the original array:

```js
var array = [5, 3, 4, 1, 2],
  len = array.length * 2 - 2;

for (var i = 1; i < len; i = i + 2) {
  array.splice(i, null, (array[i-1] + array[i]) / 2);
}

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let createdArr = [] 
[5, 3, 4, 1, 2].forEach( (item,index,arr) => {
   createdArr.push(item)
   if( index !== 0 && index + 1 !== arr.length ){
      createdArr.push( (item + arr[ index + 1]) / 2 )
   }
} )
```